# How can an Objective-C object type also be a class?

Tags: objective-c, class, types, compiler-construction

How can an Objective-C object type (which is a struct, right?) also be a class (which is a struct *)?

Is the `NSObject` inside the messaging brackets actually the `objc_class` structure, which has a pointer to the metaclass in which are stored the class methods?  If so, how can the same term also be a type to assign to `anObject`?

As in: `NSObject * anObject = [NSObject alloc] init];`

Comment: Is there something funky going on in the preprocessor or compiler to make this work?

Comment: Or, alternately, how can a type without physical reality be applied as an actual entity to which one can send messages?

Comment: A little prying under the hood revealed that the NSObject inside the brackets is indeed the objc_class structure with details of the actual object that is loaded by the module loader.  This points directly to the metaclass, of course.  So it is a very different animal than the NSObject type declaring anObject.  However, the type is readily expressed as a typedef'ed objc_object, which is of course essentially the same thing as the objc_class.

Answer (score 0):

You might be over thinking this; it is down to the *definition* of the language. A language can use the same *syntactical* elements in different contexts to represent different *semantics*.

The sub-expression:

```
[NSObject alloc]
```

means "send the `alloc` message to the class object for the type `NSObject`. So `NSObject` is being used to identify a class object. Whereas the declaration:

```
NSObject *anObject;
```

means "allocate a variable of the correct size to hold a value of type `NSObject *` and give it the name `anObject`. So here `NSObject` is being used to identify a type.

The two uses are clearly closely related, hence the use of similar *syntax* elements, but they have different *semantics*.

HTH

---

*Addendum*

If it helps, the declaration:

```
NSObject *anObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

is *by definition* roughly equivalent to:

```
Class objectClass = objc_getClass("NSObject");
NSObject *anObject = [[objectClass alloc] init];
```

but with the extra, language specification/compile time, requirement that `NSObject` must be an accessible type rather than just characters in a string (`"NSObject"`).

Comment: Syntax vs semantics is confusing to me.  If I were to put a vanilla C compiler onto that basic declaration, and expect it to know the difference between the two, it would be confused as well.  It will give me an error on either the type NSObject at the beginning, or the id NSObject in the message brackets.  I'm looking for how the compiler knows the difference.

Comment: @PaulBjork - The compiler knows the difference the same way you do, from *context*. Computer languages (usually) have *context sensitive grammars*, the grammar being the rules that define when a particular collection of lexical tokens (think "words" in a human language) form a valid program. For an English language example consider "I live in a house" and "This is a live broadcast" - the meaning, and pronunciation, of "live" depend on the context.

Answer (score 0):

An Objective-C object is not necessarily a `struct`. Once upon a time they (mostly) were, but at least since Objective-C 2.0 a bit more than a decade ago, they needn't be.

Most obvious example: the `nil` object. It is an object that accepts any message and returns `nil`. It is not a struct. It does not exist in memory.

Second-most obvious example: in the 64-bit runtime, anything that is stored in a tagged pointer is not a struct as the thing that is ostensibly a pointer doesn't actually point to anything. It is the value of the object. There is nothing on the heap.

Various other examples exist; but unless you want to define a struct very widely to be "any collection of bits that mean something", an object is not necessarily a struct.

The `NSObject` in `[[NSObject alloc] init]` is a reference to the single instance of the metaclass for `NSObject`, which has a representation somewhere in memory. Like any other reference to a global, it'll be stubbed in your binary and, ordinarily, the actual address will be substituted by the dynamic linker.

That's assuming strong linkage and/or that the symbol is found. If you weak link, then if there were no `NSObject`, the linker would simply place in a reference to the `nil` object.

You could equally perform `[[NSClassFromString(@"NSObject") alloc] init]`, but with a slightly different effect: an attempt will be made to look up the metaclass at runtime. So that's not what the compiler will ordinarily generate, but with a slight runtime cost it will allow messaging will continue exactly as if you'd named the class statically and linked weakly.

Comment: So is the NSObject in the message brackets identically the metaclass objc_class structure definition?  That's confusing, because anything else in that position has to be type id, which is objc_object *.  Or is it the class objc_class structure definition, whose isa points to the metaclass?

Comment: Now when you say "it'll be stubbed in your binary and, ordinarily, the actual address will be substituted by the dynamic linker", how is that actually accomplished?  Somehow, it knows that this is a class to reference, not just any old id instance that just gets passed right through.  And somehow the address of or the pointer to that instance of metaclass is found and substituted in.  Can you elaborate on the mechanism, please?

Comment: @PaulBjork it appears to be explicitly the duty of the Objective-C preprocessor to distinguish between metaclass references and other expressions in method dispatches. E.g. with GCC 7.1.1 I found that `NSLog(@"%p", NSObject);` is invalid, `NSObject *NSObject; NSLog(@"%p", NSObject);` is valid, and `NSObject *NSObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];` produces an undefined behaviour warning as the compiler considers the `alloc` to be dispatched to the instance you've named, not the metaclass. So likely it's just an extra step in name resolution: if not in scope as a variable, is it a known metaclass?

Comment: (And apologies for the hand-waving reasoning; Apple has never supplied a full formal definition of the Objective-C syntax other than implicitly via its open source compiler implementations such that I'm aware, and I lack the ability quickly to be able to go LLVM diving)

Comment: Excellent response, Tommy.  I'll look into those preprocessor cases that you mentioned.  For now, I find that NSObject_t * anObject = [[NSobject alloc] init]; does the trick for me.  Interestingly enough, I'm hacking the GCC runtime and GNUStep code to run on a vanilla C-compiler to run on a micro controller.  I've just about got a minimal implementation of NSObject, NSString, and NSArray (and hidden classes) fully up and running.

Comment: @Tommy - "Objective-C preprocessor"? This does not exist *per se*. The C pre-processor is run on Objective-C code but it has no involvement in resolving "metaclass references" *et al*. It is the syntax and semantic analysis phases of a compiler which handle this. In the expression `[NSObject alloc]` the `NSObject` is syntactically an identifier/type name and semantically a reference to the class object. It is a poor show that Apple never formally defined Objective-C (and the Swift definition sadly is not an exemplar of the art :-(), but standard language theory gets us a fair way.

Comment: @CRD yeah, I'm probably at least 30 years out of date in thinking that Objective-C gets transcompiled to C and then handed to the real compiler; obviously all Objective-C constructs can be expressed via the C runtime but there's no intermediate .c where that has actually happened. I definitely made an error in using a formal term that nowadays actually refers to a different and real step, while meaning to talk in less formal terms; I agree with your correction.

Comment: I see that what I am trying to do, namely make that "intermediate c" code for a smallish micro controller, is not how it is actually compiled anymore.  I've suspected that my implementation capability will be fairly limited.  As long as I can get over my final hurdle of using macros to handle dynamic class changes into the hidden class sets like NSString and NSArray.  In a modern objective-C compiler, what part interprets the [] bracket structure?  I've been using macros like mMsgSend(id, Sel, ...) to implement the message [id Sel ...], but all the particulars need to be known at compile time.

Comment: @Tommy - Ah I see, the "preproccesor" you refer to was the whole of the first compiler when Obj-C was "twice compiled", understood.  Also these days `nil` denotes the *abscence* of any object and not the *prescence* of the "nil object", did the original system use a nil object (which is a valid approach)?

Comment: @PaulBjork - What you're trying to do is a bit clearer to me now. There is nothing wrong, or limiting, in targeting C (it is just a high-level assembler after all), rather I suspect your problem lies in trying to do the conversion at the string/token/lexical level, including using macros. To compile the message send you need to do semantic analysis to determine whether you have a `Class` valued expression, which includes single variable expressions, or a single type name which in that context (see the comment on my answer) denotes the class object. *[continued...]*

Comment: *[...continued]* I.e. In `[x ...]` the *x* could be a variable/expr of type `Class` or a type name denoting the class object. Given the type name could be that of a user-defined type without some sort of semantic analysis, which builds up a symbol table as it goes, handling this reliably is nigh on impossible.

Comment: "The NSObject in [[NSObject alloc] init] is a reference to the single instance of the metaclass for NSObject" The message is sent to the class object for `NSObject`, not the metaclass object. (The class of the class object is the metaclass object.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the bracket syntax in Objective-C has two separate syntactical cases:

```
[<expression> <selector and arguments>]

[<class name> <selector and arguments>]
```

Although you can do `[NSObject alloc]`, a class name like `NSObject` is not an expression by itself in Objective-C -- trying to use `NSObject` as if it were an expression anywhere else in the code would produce an error (and that's why we are forced to write `[NSObject class]` when we need an expression that evaluates to a pointer to the class object). Rather, when you write `[NSObject alloc]`, it is using the second case of the bracket syntax, where the thing in front is a class name, and not an expression.

You can imagine what happens when the compiler compiles the second case of the bracket syntax like `[NSObject alloc]` is that it translates it into the first case of the bracket syntax, but for the expression, it uses an internal pointer to the `NSObject` class object, kind of like if you did `[objc_getClass("NSObject") alloc]` except that it doesn't need a runtime lookup and it links the value directly at compile-time.

(By the way, in Smalltalk, which is where Objective-C's object system is derived from, a class name *is* an expression (evaluating to the class object), so the syntax for sending messages in Smalltalk (which is almost identical to Objective-C except without brackets) doesn't need the two separate cases above -- the first case already covers the second. I believe they didn't want to make class names expressions when they made Objective-C because having the same identifier be both a type and an expression would have caused issues with the C parser.)